# Blockjoin faceting

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solr4

Solr's blockjoin faceting is supported only on a field. (I can specifiy parameters like **child.facet.field=${childAttribute}**)

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/blockjoin-faceting.html

Is there a similar thing i can use for intervals and ranges
(child.facet.query, child.facet.interval, child.facet.range)

I need to generate the number of parent document matches in various intervals of my child attribute.

Any pointers would be appreciated